# Place csv file into multiple value dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, csv, dictionary, filehelpers

I have a csv file as this:

```
Name,Gender,Age ,Occupation
Joe,M,29,Doctor
Carl,M,34,Accountant
Bob,M,25,Engineer
Anna,F,32,Model
```

I wanted to pass this csv file into a dictionary. The key of the dictionary will be the name of the each individual and each key will have hold 3 different values which will be the gender, age and occupation. I am using `Filehelper` to read the csv file. Here is the class for the csv file:

```
namespace ReadCSV
{
    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    [IgnoreFirst(1)]
    public class Orders
    {
        public String Name;

        public String Gender;

        public Int32 Age;

        public String Occupation;
    }
}
```

Here is main method:

```
namespace ReadCSV
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>();
            var records = engine.ReadFile("SampleCSV.csv");
            var dict = new Dictionary<String, dynamic>();

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
               //I need to place the csv file into the dictionary here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to convert the csv file into a dictionary with multiple values. After I do this, I wanted to retrieve the particular key value pair from the dictionary, for example if I call:

```
dict["Bob"]["Age"] //ignore the syntax
```

should return me `25`
Thank you very much....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill the dictionary like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>();
        var records = engine.ReadFile("SampleCSV.csv");

        // Notice the change here. Only use dynamic if you *really* need it
        var dict = new Dictionary<String, Orders>();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
           //either this:
           dict[record.Name] = record;

           //or this:
           dict.Add(record.Name, record);

           //(but not both!)
        }
    }
}
```

And then reference Bob's age like this:

```
var age = dict["Bob"].Age;
//age will now be 25
```

You cannot get this:

```
var age = dict["Bob"]["Age"];
```

*This is just not how the .Net Dictionary type works,* and nothing you do will change that. If you want that kind of lookup ability, you'll have to switch to javascript, implement a special indexer property on your `Orders` type, or change the dictionary code to create a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>`.